# Python Parsing File Remove Section

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have the following text inside of a file

input.txt

```
   :Quote_one (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("abc1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number One")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)


:Quote_two (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :uuid ("def456")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Two")
    :Address (
        : (
            :num ("1234")
            :city ("Dallas")
            :state ("TX")
        )

    )
    :Numbers (
        : (
            :num1 ("345-222-1111")
            :num2 (123)
            :num3 (456)
        )

    )
    :Names (
        : ("Test")
        : ("Test2")
        : ("Test3")

    )
)


   :Quote_three (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("xyz1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Three")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)
```

And i want to parse the file and want to remove the following section "Quote_two" so it looks like this

```
   :Quote_one (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("abc1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number One")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)

   :Quote_three (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("xyz1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Three")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)
```

I have the following code to parse through the file and i can get it to where it reads and can find Quote_two but then it just stops processing after that, so it doesn't continue to go through it and parse the file so it can write a new file without Quote_two section. Can someone help me figure this out please. All the print lines are just there so i can debug.

```
first_line = ":Quote_two (\n"
last_line = ")\n"
last_section = ":Names (\n"
in_section = False
spacer_one = False
spacer_two = False




def checkLine(line):
    open  = "("
    close = ")"
    final = ""

    if open in line and close in line:
        final = "Both"
    elif open in line and close not in line:
        final = "Open"
    elif close in line and open not in line:
        final = "Close"
    else:
        final = "Nothing"

    return final

with open('input.txt') as infile, open('input_new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
       #print line + " comparing to " + first_line + "\n"
       if line.strip() == first_line.strip():
           in_section = True
           print "Section hit true: " + line

       if not in_section:
           outfile.write(line)

       if in_section:
           if checkLine(line.strip()) != "Nothing":
               #print checkLine(line.strip()) + " current check " + line.strip()
               if line.strip() == last_section.strip():
                   print line.strip() + " : " + last_section.strip() + "\n"
                   print checkLine(line.strip()) + " : " + " Is the status"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work

```
^:Quote_two \([\s\S]+?[\r\n]+\)
```

Use the code generator button at regex101 to get a Python code sample.

https://regex101.com/r/g2I9ET/1/

---

If you enable `re.DOTALL` then this would be equivalent:

```
^:Quote_two \(.+?[\r\n]+\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/JHp1GL/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ztYHFc/2)):

```
import re

s = '''
   :Quote_one (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("abc1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number One")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)

:Quote_two_extended (
 ...
)

:Quote_two (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :uuid ("def456")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Two")
    :Address (
        : (
            :num ("1234")
            :city ("Dallas")
            :state ("TX")
        )

    )
    :Numbers (
        : (
            :num1 ("345-222-1111")
            :num2 (123)
            :num3 (456)
        )

    )
    :Names (
        : ("Test")
        : ("Test2")
        : ("Test3")

    )
)


   :Quote_three (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("xyz1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Three")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)
'''

s = re.sub(r':Quote_two\s+.*?(?=:Quote_|\Z)', '', s, flags=re.S)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
   :Quote_one (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("abc1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number One")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)

:Quote_two_extended (
 ...
)

:Quote_three (
    :parent (QUOTES_ALL)
    :id ("xyz1234")
    :display_name ("Quote Number Three")
    :children (
        : (Quotes)
        : (Sayings)

    )
)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about regex101.com , looks like a very useful site!

Comment: That was perfect, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much. Just a quick question though, i just added a Quote_two_extended section to the file and i noticed its removing that as well. Is there a way to only remove the Quote_two and not just anything that has Quote_two in the line?